# find using concatenate column using spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 1 table with 5 column, I want to find using contatenation between column1, column2 and column3 using "Like" Pattern.

Trim(column1)+Trim(Column2)+Trim(column3) LIKE %search%

is there any shortcut to make this using spring-data-jpa without using native query?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If by "shortcut" you mean "defining the query by using a fitting method name in your repository interface" as documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), the answer is no. Spring data does not support string methods like "trim" in it's method naming strategy.

However, you can define a JPAQL query to your repository method with the `@Query` annotation (which is not a native query!) like this:

```java
@Query("select e from MyEntity e where concat(trim(column1), trim(column2), trim(column3)) like %:searchString%")
List<MyEntity> findBySearchString(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

Answer (score 1):

In te entity use the annotation @Formula:

```
@Formula( "CONCAT_WS( ' ', field1, field2 ) " )
private String concatFields;
```

And in the repository just find by that field;

```
findByConcatFieldsContains( String text );
```